# Run time Error 91 when using excel object in access

Tags: vba, object, ms-access, runtime-error

I have a problem. I am trying to get records from the data base to Excel and afterwards format the Excel file. If I implement the whole function then it will run fine on one occasion. But if I run it again it sometimes gives the runtime 91 error. I was going through the debugging and if I only have the first ApXl in the function the code will work fine with no issues. However, if I add more of the code to reformat the Excel sheet then it will eventually give me the run time 91 even though the variables are already declared. Below is part of my code with some of the formatting.

```
Public Function ExportToExcelEM(Numbcases, strObjectType As String, strObjectName As String, Optional strSheetName As String, Optional strFileName As String)

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ApXL As Object
    Dim xlWBk As Object
    Dim xlWSh As Object
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Const xlToRight As Long = -4161
    Const xlCenter As Long = -4108
    Const xlBottom As Long = -4107
    Const xlContinuous As Long = 1
    Dim OBJ As Object

    On Error GoTo ExportToExcel_Err
    DoCmd.Hourglass True

    Select Case strObjectType

    Case "Table", "Query"
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strObjectName, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    Case "Form"
        Set rst = Forms(strObjectName).RecordsetClone
    Case "Report"
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Reports(strObjectName).RecordSource, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    End Select

    If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No records to be exported.", vbInformation, GetDBTitle
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ApXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        End If
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ExportToExcel_Err

        Set xlWBk = ApXL.Workbooks.Add
        ApXL.Visible = False

        Set xlWSh = xlWBk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If Len(strSheetName) > 0 Then
            xlWSh.Name = Left(strSheetName, 31)
        End If

        xlWSh.Range("A1").Select
        Do Until intCount = rst.Fields.Count
            ApXL.ActiveCell = rst.Fields(intCount).Name
            ApXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            intCount = intCount + 1
        Loop

        rst.MoveFirst
         
        xlWSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

   **  **  ** With ApXL
            .Range("A1").Select
            .Range(.Selection, .Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            .Selection.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            .Selection.Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Selection.Interior.TintAndShade = -0.25
            .Selection.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
            .Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
            .Selection.AutoFilter
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
            .Range("B2").Select
            .ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
            .ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
            .ActiveSheet.Cells.WrapText = False
            .ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Visible = False
            End With********
    With ApXL
    xlWSh.Rows(1).Select
      With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    End With

  xlWBk.SaveAs FileName:=strFileName, FileFormat:=51
        xlWBk.Close
    Set xlWBk = Nothing
    Set xlWSh = Nothing
    Set ApXL = Nothing
    ' end of doing anything with excel
 End If

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
DoCmd.Hourglass False
ExportToExcel_Exit:
DoCmd.Hourglass False
Exit Function
ExportToExcel_Err:
 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 Set xlWBk = Nothing
    Set xlWSh = Nothing
    Set ApXL = Nothing
    rst.Close
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
   DoCmd.Hourglass False
Resume ExportToExcel_Exit

End Function
```

debugging:  works once after adding more formatting in my code but then gives me a runtime 91 error. I added more code chunks to the code till it was the complete excel function I desired. Throughout the process it would give me the finish piece I wanted but afterwards gives me a runtime error 91.

Comment: You've used a number of Excel named constants that Access vba won't know.  You've also decalred some as constants,  so you know how to fix it.  FYI if you add Option Explict to the top of the module it'll help you identify them all

Comment: Stubbing out the code would be way to much work, but With Selection looks suspicously like an undeclared variable.  If option explicit is causing you too much trouble try either replacing Selection with xlWSh.Rows(1).Select or setting Selection: I think xlWSh.Rows(1).Select is a range so in that case Dim Selection as Range; Set Selection = xlWSh.Rows(1).Select  all using With ApXL

Answer (score 1):

After running procedure, check if instance of Excel is still showing in Task Manager. This can be result of using `Active______` referencing. Use explicit reference instead.

When I compile your procedure, I get "Method or data member not found." error on each line in the `xlWSh.Rows(1).Select` block. Use `With .Rows(1)` instead.

Could probably perform this process without actually selecting anything. Use explicit Cells or Range reference: `With .Range("A1:E1")` - construct reference with variables.

Modified your code to apply and it works:

```
intCount = rst.Fields.Count
Set xlWSh = xlWBk.worksheets("Sheet1")
With xlWSh
    If strSheetName <> "" Then .Name = Left(strSheetName, 31)
    For x = 1 To intCount
        .Cells(1, x).Value = rst(x - 1).Name
    Next
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, intCount))
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.25
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .AutoFilter
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    With .Rows(1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .shrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    .Rows.AutoFit
End With
ApXL.Windows(1).SplitColumn = 1
ApXL.Windows(1).SplitRow = 1
ApXL.Windows(1).FreezePanes = True
```